# can I flash stock sony z2 ROM on my Xolo play 1100 directly

Tags: rom-flashing

I want to replace my full phone interface with Sony z2 I have both the phones right now. So I was thinking to make a full cwm recovery of my z2 and flash it my xolo. 
I know might be it won't work like that but if suppose I download the stock ROM of z2 from internet and correctly flash that to my Xolo will it work. (Can one run another other companies stock ROM on other phone)

Plz advice me the most correct method.

***hardware specification of both the phone are approximately same***

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do it, unless you were born with the golden spoon in your mouth. Ok on serious note, flashing different device's ROM to another device, will **NOT** work. It will brick your device. Once I flashed GT-S5570i ROM on GT-5570, My phone was dead, I thought a small "i" wont matter..But it did.

Look [Here.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/can-i-install-a-rom-made-for-a-different-device)