# Will klte ROMs work on SM-G800F?

Tags: custom-roms

I want to install AOKP on my Vodaphone Samsung Galaxy S5 mini SM-G800F, however, the kminilte ROM is not yet developed.

klte seems the closest to kminilte, so will installing it brick my phone, or will it be successful? What features of my hardware will be voided by installing the wrong version if it successes?

---

Edit as I cannot add an answer as this question is a duplicate.

I actually started dabbling in things regarding porting (slightly modifying ROMs for different devices). And the differences are huge. In the script that initializes the rest of the system, it tests for different models of klte, thus not finding a result and not booting.

Regardless of that, the CPU, screen size, pixel density etc. is different.

If someone has an unsupported device, they can try to find the most similar supported devices to keep change to minimum. You can also look on the CM wiki for unofficial ports.

When comparing devices, I recommend the webpage http://pdadb.net/ as it gives very detailed info about android phones.

Comment: @Firelord I aggree, and I flagged my own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very bright chances of bricking your phone if you flash a ROM **not** specifically meant for your phone. Custom ROMs are made by developers to cater explicitly for models specified by them, and being "closest" to your phone model doesn't mean anything in this context. Please read these to get more understanding

- [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/can-i-install-a-rom-made-for-a-different-device):
- [Feasibility of flashing a ROM (meant for original device) on a re-branded device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128536/feasibility-of-flashing-a-rom-meant-for-original-device-on-a-re-branded-device)

I don't know if your phone is "tied to a carrier", or is not , but even flashing a ROM meant for a specific device and carrier on same device but different carrier can successfully brick your phone, and that is the reason developers also mention the carrier it will work on where relevant

Second part of your question, *What features of my hardware will be voided by installing the wrong version if it successes?*, is redundant given the explanation above.