# CyanogenMod on an unsupported device

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, karbonn

I'm using a Karbonn A52+ running Mediatek processor and Android 4.2.2 Jellybean. My device is rooted, but unfortunately, no custom recovery (CWM / TWRP) is supported for my device. There is also no CyanogenMod build available for my phone.

Still, I was planning to give a try to [this method](http://beta.download.cyanogenmod.org/install)

Unfortunately, CyanogenMod has shutted down all its systems, including its webpage; so probably, link would also not work.

Now, is there any risk of my phone getting bricked? If yes, then soft brick or hard brick? If my phone gets bricked, can I repair it by simply flashing the stock ROM?

Comment: Please take a look at [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) and [Can I install any ROM for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) A ROM must be made specifically for the device it should run on. If it's not, you risk some things not working (best case) or bricking your device (worst case). Cause are the not-open-source hardware elements: each device has different of them.

Comment: The link you gave us is dead. Soft-bricks can usually be taken care by doing factory reset but hard-bricks may be fatal though a lot of the cases are solved for MTK devices such as yours by using SP Flash Tools. In any case, if a CM build isn't available then you shouldn't try any insensible thing (like that link) and neither cling to any hope either.

Answer (score -1):

It is always best to install CM Roms that is suited for your device.

If you can't find one, then it's best to stick with it.  The risk will always be there, when you force something into your device that isn't compatible with it.

*Hope this helps ...*