# Custom OS samsung galaxy e5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Is there any chance of installing official Samsung galaxy s5 6.0 marshmallow firmware on samsung galaxy e5 using odin?

Comment: See: [Can I install any ROM for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575) A ROM must match your device (i.e. its especially tailored for it).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install official firmware on the samsung galaxy e5. However samsung hasn't released a marshmallow update for the e5 yet.

In the android ROM community they call official firmware, "stock".
When looking for posts online it is best to search for "flashing stock rom Firmware"

You can use Odin to install the official samsung galaxy e5 firmware. Be aware that there are multiple versions of the samsung galaxy e5 and you need to find the correct firmware for your device. Too view your device model go to -> settings -> About Phone -> device model.

There is however a unofficial cyanogenmod rom available for the samsung galaxy e5(E500H only) that has marshmallow.
[Forum post to E500H Cyanogenmod](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-e-series/orig-development/rom-cyanogenmod-13-galaxy-e5-e500h-t3290755)

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point. Can you please tell me more clearly?

Comment: Hardware of Samsung Galaxy E5 and Samsung Galaxy S5 are approximately same, so does Galaxy S5 firmware supports in Galaxy E5?

Comment: Im sorry! I thought you asked for the samsung galaxy s5. I didnt know there is a e5.

Comment: Hopefully this gives a better explanation. You cannot use the s5 firmware. You must be sure to use the firmware that is exactly made for your model.