# What will happen if I flash a custom rom for GT-I9082 on a GT-I9060c/m/i?

Tags: rom-flashing

I have a Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo Plus/DUOS (GT-I9060C) and I would like to know what will happen if I FLASH A Custom Rom for the Galaxy Grand Neo DUOS (GT-I9082) Onto my phone (GT-I9060C)

Will it be Hard-Bricked,Soft Bricked or will it work fine

Custom ROM description : Lineage OS (Android 7.1)
Linux 3.0
Supports dual sim

Current rom: Rooted Stock rom 4.4.4 kitkat SuperSU  Pro running TWRP 3.0 For GT-I9060I (idk how gt-i9060i twrp recovery worked on the gt-i9060c
With AKAS security software (idk what that is)

---

Hmm So if i did flashed the rom and its soft bricked (repairable) will i still be able to use DownLoad Mode because i heard some people said that it will hard brick your phone (unrepairable) if you install roms that wasnt met for your phone. Also im on GT-I9060C not on GT-I9060I because i9060i doesnt have a magnetic sensor

Heres some description about my phone:

[image: Pic1] [image: Pic2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/can-i-install-a-rom-made-for-a-different-device)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similarities of the 2 devices are mostly only in their name. [Grand Duos (i9082)](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=4058&c=samsung_gt-i9082_galaxy_grand_duos__samsung_baffin) is out Jan 2013 and uses a Broadcom BCM28155 SoC, while [Grand Neo Plus Duos (i9060i)](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=device&id=7588&c=samsung_gt-i9060i_galaxy_grand_neo_plus_duos) along with its family are out circa 2015 and use a Broadcom BCM23550 SoC.

Recovery will reject ROMs made for a different device, and even if you manage to flash it in, it won't boot due to the hardware difference (soft-brick in your words).