# Can I flash a rom, that is not exactly made for my phone, but has the some socket (MT6753)?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, 7.1-nougat

My phone is an Elephone P6000 Pro with Android 5.1 and I want to flash the Vernee Thor's 7.1 rom. Both of the phone has MT6753. Is it possible?

Comment: Generally, no... Android ROM's are VERY device specific, even a minor difference in hardware or configuration can cause permanent hard brick of the device.

Comment: If you still want to flash, don't flash the preloader, otherwise you kill your phone

Comment: I think the first thing is if the kernel matches the ROM features, otherwise, so many functions would freeze.

Comment: Please see: [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575)

Comment: Hmmm... i think i will not try, i'm too scared

Answer (score 0):

Very bad idea.

They may use the same processor but other things you don't know about yet, are different. If the code isn't optimized for it, you are very likely to run into problems