# Can I install Android P Beta to my Galaxy S8?

Tags: updates, google

I want to install Android P Beta to my Galaxy S8 device but after I went to https://www.google.com/android/beta I can see that only Pixel 2 device can opt out for an upgrade.

Is it ok if I opt out for the Pixel version or this will be dangerous for my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be disastrous to do that !

- As you mentioned it is only for Pixel device and flashing it on your device is same as asked here [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/131553)
- Your device doesn't have [treble](/questions/tagged/treble) 
  support as [mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS8/comments/88yf1x/treble_support/) and you are wanting to flash a treble based ROM, which requires major changes to be done by developers

Unless you fancy an expensive paper weight , don't

Comment: The one available on Google's site isn't even a Treble GSI - some XDA people had to port it over.