# Can I install replicant on a Galaxy A10e without bricking it?

Tags: rooting, samsung, security, custom-roms, privacy

I'm trying to UnGoogle my phone for privacy/security reasons, and from one source I heard that if you want to use a smartphone, you're better off getting a Pinephone running GrapheneOS / LineageOS. But the problem is I have a Samsung and there's no way I would be able to install those types of custom ROMs on my device without essentially destroying it. I wonder if you can install replicant.us on a Samsung phone. Any help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35925/can-i-install-a-rom-made-for-a-different-device)

Comment: If it is not meant for you phone, don't try

Comment: Installing a pure open source OS on phones is the dream of many. But unfortunately proprietorship is so deep rooted in software. Particularly in phones world. There aren't many people who practically support Replicant. Ubuntu also miserably failed trying to achieve something similar. Graphene/Lineage aren't fully open source though (vendor HALs are always proprietary), but still much better than ROMs shipped by many OEMs. In fact Google is not the only entity you need to get rid of. Phones in particular are by design meant to have closed source components. There's no way to fully avoid it.