# Installing firmware SM-A015F to SM-A015AZ hardware

Tags: samsung, odin

i have a SM-A015AZ and their is no OEM unlocking feature and i want to install magisk i updated the firmware manually with Odin but no luck i now want to install SM-A015F firmware on my SM-A015AZ phone i feagured it would work since they have the same specks and same hardware*.

Comment: Not a good idea to flash ROM meant for another model https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/16575