# Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2-830L & 830LC & 830F > Firmwares

Tags: rom-flashing, tablet, device-firmware, lenovo

I have a [Lenovo Yoga Tablet 2](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd104169-overview-for-yoga-tablet-2-830)-**[830L](https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=9494)** and I installed a firmware from **[830LC](https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=9575)** on that device.
It is working with no problem.

The difference between these two firmware types is :

> The 'L' models don't support calling.  The 'LC' models support calling
> (dialler app).
>
> If there were an LC version, you could probably install the LC
> firmware on your L model.  That would add calling, but void your
> warranty.

I want to know can I install firmware from **[830F](https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=9568)** on **[830L](https://firmware.gem-flash.com/index.php?a=downloads&b=folder&id=9494)** device?
What are differences between **YT2-830L** and **YT2-830LC** and **YT2-830F**?

Comment: *I want to know can i install a firmware from **[830F][4]** on **[830L][2]** device?* **NO, you can't**  See [Can I install a ROM made for a different device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/35925/131553) //For differences between models, sites like GSM Arena, XDA are better alternatives

Comment: @beeshyams I know - But these models are the same. Means YT2-830L & YT2-830LC & YT2-830F.

Comment: If they are the same it's unlikely they will have different model numbers